# Why can't a const method return a non-const reference?

Tags: c++, c++11, reference, constants, const-cast

Why won't the method `getRanks()` below compile, and how can I fix it gracefully?

All I want do is define a member accessor method that returns a reference to a member. The reference is not `const` since I might well modify what it refers to later. But since the member method does not modify the object, I declare it `const`. The compiler (clang, std=c++11) then insists that there is a "binding of reference" that "drops qualifiers". But I'm NOT dropping qualifiers, am I? And if I am, why:

```
struct teststruct{
  vector<int> ranks;
  vector<int>& getRanks()const{
    return ranks;
  }
};
```

Now, the code compiles if I change the return statement to cast away the const:

```
return const_cast<vector<int>&>(ranks);
```

But "ranks" should not be const in the first place, I don't see why I need to const_cast the const away. I don't even know if it's safe to do this.

Anyway, is there a cleaner to write this method? Can someone explain why such a simple common-sense method fails? I do want to declare the `getRanks()` method "`const`" so that I can call it from other `const` methods.

Comment: `teststruct const x; x.getRanks().emplace_back();` -> UB.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The idea behind the `const` member function is you should be able to call them on `const` objects. `const` functions can't modify the object.

Say you have a class

```
class A
{
   int data;
   void foo() const
   {
   }
};
```

and on object and a function call:

```
A const a;
a.foo();
```

Inside `A::foo`, `this->data` is treated as if its type is `int const`, not `int`. Hence, you are not able to modify `this->data` in `A:foo()`.

Coming to your example, the type of `this->ranks` in `getRanks()` is to be considered as `const vector<int>` and not `vector<int>`. Since, auto conversion of `const vector<int>` to `vector<int>&` is not allowed, the compiler complains when you define the function as:

```
vector<int>& getRanks()const{
    return ranks;
  }
```

It won't complain if you define the function as:

```
const vector<int>& getRanks()const{
    return ranks;
  }
```

since `const vector<int>` can be auto converted to `const vector<int>&`.

Answer (score 4):

`ranks` is `const` because the enclosing object (`*this`) is `const`, so you have to return a reference to a `std::vector<int> const`.

If you want to allow the client to modify the vector (and thereby affecting the member), then the getter should not be `const`. Note that the getter is silly anyway, since `ranks` is already a public data member.

Comment: If getter is not const, it cannot be called from a const method. But I want to do do that, I want to call it sometimes from const method, sometimes from non_const methods.

Comment: @kdog then make two getters, one const and one non-const.

Comment: A la [`std::vector::operator[]`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/operator_at).

Answer (score 1):

You are returning a reference to `ranks`, which is a member of `teststruct`. That means that anybody that gets this reference could modify the internals of the `teststruct` object. So the `const` is a lie.

Don't cast away the `const`. Instead, decide between whether you want the function to be `const` and return a copy of `ranks` or `const` reference, or to be non-`const` and return a mutable reference. You can always have both if necessary.

Comment: But hold on. I thought a "const" just before the semicolon in the declaration of a method just meant that that method ITSELF did not modify the object of which it is a member function. That's what the Stroustrup book says if I recall. I am not declaring that any usage from now into the future of the returned will not modify the object. I am just declaring that the function itself will not. And I DO wan t to return a reference that can be modified, not a copy! Also is the const_cast idea safe to use?

Comment: @kdog Well this would allow the method to indirectly cause the object to be modified. The `const_cast` idea is not safe, because the compiler can make assumptions based on the fact it believes that it won't be modified.

Comment: Rather than "the `const` is a lie", I'd say "the `const`/return type breaks const correctness".

Comment: No, the compiler should give an error at the v.push_back(42) line, not the getRanks() line...although I am beginning to see the issue. Why is this so confusing and counterintuitive to me and obvious to everyone else ;-)

Comment: @kdog The `const` for the member function means that the object that the function is called on is `const`. In other words the this-pointer is const. And because `this` is const, `this->anything` is also `const`. There is no requirement for `getRanks` to return a `const &`, but there is a requirement to return an object with the return type's type.

Comment: @kdog The compiler cannot enforce *not modifying something*. That's just not possible in a low-level language that has pointer arithmetic and `const_cast` for compatibility. It has to rely on your annotation. So even a function that does not modify an object, if not declared as const, cannot be called on a const object. Here, the situation is similar. "a const member function does not modify its object" is merely a convention, consider `mutable` objects etc.

Answer (score 0):

It drops qualifiers because you return a reference to `ranks`. Any code after can modify ranks. Ex:

```
auto v = teststruct.getRanks();
v[1] = 5; //assuming v.size() > 1
```

You can fix this by returning a copy:

```
vector<int> getRanks() const
```

Or a `const` reference:

```
const vector<int>& getRanks() const
```

If you want `ranks` changable even in a `const` object, you could do this:

```
mutable vector<int> ranks;
```

Comment: No this doesn't fix it because I I might want later to modify the reference returned by getRanks(). Do I need two getRanks, one const and one not? I just want to declare that getRanks() ITSELF does not modify object. That it can be called in a const method.

Comment: No I do not want ranks to be mutable , I do want const checking.

Comment: Then it sounds like two overloads `vector<int>& getRanks();` and `const vector<int>& getRanks() const;` is what you want.