# Const method returning non-const reference compiles

Tags: c++, constants

I have a simple `Vector` class with indexing operator implemented.
Coming from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24346563/why-cant-a-const-method-return-a-non-const-reference) and other related questions, I am unsure as to why the following code compiles:

```
int main()
{
    const Vector A(5);
    cout << "A :" << A << endl;
    A[0] = 5;
    cout << "A: " << A << endl;
}
```

**Vector.h**

```
#pragma once
#include <iostream> 
#include <functional>

namespace vector
{
    class Vector
    {
        friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream&, const Vector&);

        int n;
        int *arr; 
    public:
        Vector(int = 0); 
        ~Vector();
        Vector(const Vector&);
        Vector& operator=(const Vector&);
    private:
        void copy(const Vector&);
    public:
        int& operator[](const int) const;   
    };
}
```

**Vector.cpp**

```
#include "Vector.h"
#include <algorithm>
#include <utility>
#include <functional>


namespace vector
{ 
    Vector::Vector(int n) : n(n), arr(new int[n])
    {
        std::fill(arr, arr + n, 0);
    }

    Vector::~Vector()
    {
        n = 0;
        delete[] arr;
    }

    void Vector::copy(const Vector& other)
    {
        arr = new int[n = other.n];
        std::copy(other.arr, other.arr + n, arr);
    }

    Vector::Vector(const Vector& other)
    {
        copy(other);
    }

    Vector& Vector::operator=(const Vector& other)
    {
        if (this != &other)  
        {
            this->~Vector();
            copy(other);
        }
        return *this;
    }

    int& Vector::operator[](const int index) const
    {
        return arr[index];
    }

    std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& stream, const Vector& vec)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < vec.n; i++)
            stream << vec.arr[i] << " ";

        return stream;
    }

}
```

Output:

```
A: 0 0 0 0 0
A: 5 0 0 0 0
```

How could a const method returning a non-const reference (later used to change the previously const object) even compile?

Comment: We lack the definition of `Vector::arr` to answer. Please [edit] your question to provide a [mcve].

Comment: My crystal ball tells me that you have stumbled upon the non-`const`-transitivity of pointers. [Here's a nice article on the subject](http://www.bfilipek.com/2018/01/propagate-const.html).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In short, it's your responsibility.

In `const` member function, only the data member itself becomes `const`. For `arr` (which is supposed to be of type `int*`) it'll become `int * const` (i.e. `const` pointer), not `int const *` (i.e. pointer to `const`); i.e. the pointer becomes `const` but the pointee doesn't. So technically it's possible to return a non-const reference to the pointee, even it might not make much sense in fact.

You'd better to overload on `operator[]`, like most STL containers do. e.g.

```
// const version
int const & Vector::operator[](const int index) const 
{
    return arr[index]; 
}

// non-const version
int & Vector::operator[](const int index)
{
    return arr[index]; 
}
```

Comment: You could add that, in order to achieve const-correctness, you usually provide a const and a non-const overload of `operator[]` with const and non-const return types.

Comment: I always do, this was for practice purposes only. Wanted to see what would happen with a non-const version of the method only.

Comment: No reason why the member couldn't be mutable; at which point returning a non-const reference makes a lot of sense. (eg a collection of mutexs)

Answer (score 0):

`const` in a method declaration only means that the method has read only access to the instance itself (as if it receives `const MyType *this` rather than `MyType *this`). If `arr` is a pointer to `int` in your class, it will be respectively considered as `int * const` when used inside a `const` method. But please note that it's not the same as `const int *` ! That's why dereferencing it yields an `int&`, not `const &int` .